# update-initramfs never doing work

Tags: raspbian, compute-module

i'm trying to add some scripts to the /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-bottom folder to manipulate some partitions and files before boot. when i run `update-initramfs -u` it always gives back

> nothing to do, exiting

trying the same thing on my PC updates initramfs successfully and everything works as it should.

am i missing something ? is the raspbian image modified somehow or something is missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> trying the same thing on my PC updates initramfs successfully

Yes, because generally speaking PC oriented distros actually use an initramfs because they *must*.  The reason they must is because they are intended to run on a wide variety of hardware, some of which requires mutually incompatible drivers.  This means you cannot build the drivers into the kernel, they must be loadable modules that the kernel selects when it identifies the hardware it is running on.

Such dynamically loadable modules are stored in the root filesystem (`/lib/modules/...`).  However, this is a problem if they are required in order to mount and access the root filesystem, and that is the primary purpose of an initramfs -- it's a small, read-only, archived filesystem that (I believe) the bootloader provides access to.  This is used to select appropriate drivers from, mount the real root fs, and then discarded.

The Raspberry Pi kernel is not intended to be run on a variety of hardware.  It's intended for use only on one very specific platform, and so any essential modules necessary to accessing the root filesystem can be build into it, hence an initramfs is an unnecessary complication.

So it does not use one (and updating something that doesn't exist would equate to "nothing to do").  If you want to use one, you would have to build the kernel yourself in order to facilitate that.

> i'm trying to ... manipulate some partitions and files before boot

This is maybe just the wrong choice of words, but as implied above, an initramfs can't do anything *before* boot, it's used to do something during the boot process (after the kernel is loaded and before the primary root fs is mounted).

In any case, it might be worth considering this as an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  Don't get into using a custom kernel unless you know you absolutely need to.

Comment: yeah my bad for not being clear on that part (by before boot i meant just after mounting the root file system the idea is to mount a unionfs with ro /). we definitely don't want to build and maintain a custom kernel for this thing so sticking with the current solution.

Comment: What if one wants to encrypt root file system for example? "Don't do that" is not acceptable answer

Comment: Nobody's saying "don't do that"; apparently [it can be done without an initramfs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/587123/25985) (likely the reason there is not more of this for linux is that generally speaking it's normal to use an initramfs so there is not actually a great need to do it without one).   Anyway, running a lightly customized kernel is not a lot of work, it just requires a certain level of knowledge/skill, something that I do not think would be insurmountable to learn for a reasonably tech savvy person (although it might well require some tedious trial and error).

Comment: Finally, other than RpiOS and derivatives I think most (or at least, a decent number of major) Pi *compatible* distros do use an initramfs since they can often be deployed  on a range of different ARM platforms without too much fuss.   I believe there are also distros that are specifically intended for use with encrypted and/or read-only systems.